# Dropped calls and people not hearing me

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

Samsung S3 dropping calls and people not hearing me on made or received calls. Happened after latest upgrade.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a carrier problem?

Comment: Closely related: [People can't hear me on my Samsung Galaxy S3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35834)

Comment: Duplicate (with no answer): [When I send or receive a call, the person on the other side can't hear me](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44468)

Comment: You might have abandoned this question, but could you remember which update? "latest update" doesn't really help at this exact time.